# Launching multiple threads and restarting them

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to program a system where I create x amount of worker threads. These threads will finish their work in different times. When any of them complete their work, I will examine their output and restart them again (Keeping the running number of threads around x). I will do this for a number of aribitary iterations. So, basically a controller thread will launch x amount of threads, and will restart them when they finish their work, until some number of iterations are reached.

Additional Note #1 : When I said restart, it's perfectly fine to wait until the current one exits/aborts and gets destroyed, and create a new one. It doesn't have to "restart" the same thread. I'm mostly interested in doing this in a clean async way.

Note: I'm not looking for any specific code, but some possible pseudo code and a design pattern making use of slots and signals.

I'm aware of qt threads and have worked them. I'm familiar with examples where you launch an x amount of threads and wait until all of them finish using yield, and wait. I'm looking for a clean way to achieve what I described in the first paragraph using signals and slots.

Comment: Instead of restarting the threads why not launch a new one?  AFIAK threads are not meant to be reused.

Comment: restart them all together or asynchronously as they finish?

Comment: Why not a loop with some task queues ?

Comment: It's ok to not re-use them and create a new one. I guess I'm trying to understand how to do that in an async way.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Could you kindly elaborate what you mean by a task queue? Is it like an array/vector, with some bool flag, so I know it has been updated with a result by a thread? And I loop this indefinitely?

Comment: Something like [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `QtConcurrent::run()` or `QThreadPool::start()` are for. The Concurrent framework uses a thread pool internally, so they're quite equivalent: the former is a convenience wrapper for the latter. The default thread pool is best left for short-running tasks; to run long tasks, use your own thread pool. You'd pass it to `QtConcurrent::run()` as the first argument.

The `QThreadPool` maintains a queue of work items, dispatches them to threads, and dynamically creates and destroys worker threads. It's a wonderful class that you don't have to reimplement yourself.

If you don't have too many units of work and can furnish them all upfront, simply use `QtConcurrent::run()` or `QThreadPool::start()` to queue them all ahead of time. They can emit a signal from a helper object to notify you as each of them finishes.

If the units of work are too expensive to create all at once, you'll have to implement a notifying work queue on top of a thread pool.

The unit of work needs to notify the queue and its users that it has finished. This can be done e.g. by reimplementing the `QRunnable` as a base for a `WorkUnit`, forwarding the work to an abstract method, and notifying the queue when the abstract method has finished. The same approach works for `QtConcurrent::run`, except that instead of reimplementing `QRunnable::run` you implement a functor's `operator()()`.

The queue will emit a `workUnitDone` signal for every finished work unit. The user is expected to refill the queue with one item of work upon receiving the signal (or none if there's no more work).

For convenience, the queue can request a number of initial work items, by emitting `workUnitDone(nullptr)`. If you replenish exactly one item every time a previous one has finished, the queue will maintain the initial number of work items.

If the items take a very short amount of time to process, you should have many more available than the number of threads, so that no threads will be idling without work. For items that mostly take long time (tens of milliseconds or more), it's sufficient to have 1.5-2 times the `QThread::idealThreadCount`.

The work units added to the queue can be instances of `WorkUnit`, or functors.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/notified-workqueue-38000605
#include <QtCore>
#include <type_traits>

class WorkUnit;
class WorkQueue : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   friend class WorkUnit;
   QThreadPool m_pool{this};
   union alignas(64) { // keep it in its own cache line
      QAtomicInt queuedUnits{0};
      char filler[64];
   } d;
   void isDone(WorkUnit * unit) {
      auto queued = d.queuedUnits.deref();
      emit workUnitDone(unit);
      if (!queued) emit finished();
   }
public:
   explicit WorkQueue(int initialUnits = 0) {
      if (initialUnits)
         QTimer::singleShot(0, [=]{
            for (int i = 0; i < initialUnits; ++i)
               emit workUnitDone(nullptr);
         });
   }
   Q_SLOT void addWork(WorkUnit * unit);
   template <typename F> void addFunctor(F && functor);
   Q_SIGNAL void workUnitDone(WorkUnit *);
   Q_SIGNAL void finished();
};

class WorkUnit : public QRunnable {
   friend class WorkQueue;
   WorkQueue * m_queue { nullptr };
   void run() override {
      work();
      m_queue->isDone(this);
   }
protected:
   virtual void work() = 0;
};

template <typename F>
class FunctorUnit : public WorkUnit, private F {
   void work() override { (*this)(); }
public:
   FunctorUnit(F && f) : F(std::move(f)) {}
};

void WorkQueue::addWork(WorkUnit *unit) {
   d.queuedUnits.ref();
   unit->m_queue = this;
   m_pool.start(unit);
}

template <typename F> void WorkQueue::addFunctor(F && functor) {
   addWork(new FunctorUnit<typename std::decay<F>::type>{std::forward<F>(functor)});
}
```

To demonstrate things, let's do 50 units of "work" of sleeping for a random time between 1us and 1s. We're passing half of the units as `SleepyWork` instances, and another half as lambdas.

```
#include <random>

struct SleepyWork : WorkUnit {
   int usecs;
   SleepyWork(int usecs) : usecs(usecs) {}
   void work() override {
      QThread::usleep(usecs);
      qDebug() << "slept" << usecs;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   std::random_device dev;
   std::default_random_engine eng{dev()};
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{1, 1000000};
   auto rand_usecs = [&]{ return dist(eng); };

   int workUnits = 50;
   WorkQueue queue{2*QThread::idealThreadCount()};
   QObject::connect(&queue, &WorkQueue::workUnitDone, [&]{
      if (workUnits) {
         if (workUnits % 2) {
            auto us = dist(eng);
            queue.addFunctor([us]{
               QThread::usleep(us);
               qDebug() << "slept" << us;
            });
         } else
            queue.addWork(new SleepyWork{rand_usecs()});
         --workUnits;
      }
   });
   QObject::connect(&queue, &WorkQueue::finished, [&]{
      if (workUnits == 0) app.quit();
   });

   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

This concludes the example.

Comment: This seems clean and the way to go. I will implement this and inform of the progress.

Comment: Isn't there a race condition when queue (the WorkQueue) is initialized, and the connect for workUnitDone is executed. Isn't it better to initialize after the connect statement. In this case, adding an init method to WorkQueue with the initialization logic.

Comment: @dev_nut There can be no race because until the control returns to the event loop, the workqueue executes no code. The queue's constructor doesn't do much but schedule signal emission to be done from the event loop. The deferral of work to the event loop is a common pattern and exists precisely to preclude any races. That's what makes signals and slots usable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have the following for each thread:

- bool exit

  - before starting the thread, set it to false
  - main thread should only set it to true. Order is set the flag to true, join thread
  - worker thread should only set it to false. Order is exiting the loop, doing any post-processing, setting it to false, returning.
- Semaphore (no counter needed, just post / stop, as in pthreads)

  - main thread will post
  - worker thread will run in a `while( !exit )`, first command in the loop is to wait for the semaphore.
- bool threadWorking

  - before starting the thread, set it to false
  - main thread should only set it to true. Order is: have the data ready, set the flag to true, post semaphore.
  - worker thread should only set it to false. Orther is: have the answer ready, inform main thread, set the flag to false.

This way you can re-use the thread.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear enough. I have added some additional notes.